# Swiftmailer works for a couple of days and then stops working with Zoho Mail

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

I've setup Swiftmailer to work with my Zoho mail account, and curiously it works fine for a couple of days but then stops working all of a sudden without me changing anything. If I setup a new Zoho mail account and make Swiftmail use that account... it will again work for a couple of days and then stop working.

I setup the transport with:

```
$transport = new \Swift_SmtpTransport("smtp.zoho.com", 465,"ssl");
```

The error I get when it stops working is the following:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with
>   message 'Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "**[my
>   Zoho mail email address]**" using 2 possible authenticators' in
>   /home/localpow/public_html/_database_mailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/Esmtp/AuthHandler.php:181
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/localpow/public_html/_database_mailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/EsmtpTransport.php(333):
>   Swift_Transport_Esmtp_AuthHandler->afterEhlo(Object(Swift_SmtpTransport))
>    /home/localpow/public_html/_database_mailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(118):
>   Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport->_doHeloCommand() #2
>   /home/localpow/public_html/_database_mailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Mailer.php(79):
>   Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->start() #3
>   /home/localpow/public_html/_database_mailer/relay_handler.php(106):
>   Swift_Mailer->send(Object(Swift_Message)) #4 {main} thrown in
>   /home/localpow/public_html/_database_mailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/Esmtp/AuthHandler.php
>   on line 181

Not sure why it would work for awhile and then stop working all of a sudden?

(For the record, when it is working, I have only sent at most about 4 emails through the script, so it shouldn't be anything to do with sending too many emails in a certain period of time or anything like that)

Comment: Do you get it working? Got same problem too